# Java project, include frontend library(Polymer)

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee, dependencies, frontend

I try to work on apache2 licensed project on github, it is a j2ee webap, as user UI I want to use Polymer libraries...
Now I don't know to include all needed js/html files in depository or to leave only bowler file ?

- If i will include all files it will be easy to start project but entire repository will grow and probably will be required to update files when new version of frontend will be available and so on...
- If I will leave only bower file, someone who cloned project will be required to do more workarounds to start project

Someone had similar issues ? how was solved they ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to put the code under version control for these reasons:

1. It makes bootstrapping (compiling the first time) much easier
2. It doesn't cost much
3. You can track changes between versions
4. You can make your own changes against polymer components and merge then with newer releases

The last two are important if you care about quality: When a polymer component suddenly starts to break after an update, you have a comfortable way to see what changed.

Now you need to make a fix and you need to make sure that the fix survives the next update. Having all files under version control will make your life much easier.

Note: Make sure that the OSS licenses of all projects agree. If they don't, then you can't do this, no matter how much you want. In this case, the next best solution is to fork the project which doesn't fit your license and keep it separate. The normal build process should then checkout or copy the necessary files out of your fork.